# How to send stored value rather than the alias in automated bash script for interactive input

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, automation, expect

I'm trying to automate the installation of mysql on a remote sever.  I'm using golang to do various things, one of which is executing an `expect` script in bash that has several steps.  One of the steps is installing mysql and then running `mysql_secure_installation`.  The first prompt it asks the user for is a password.  This password is created at runtime so I don't know it ahead of time to include it as a literal value that I can `send`.  I get the password from the log and store that in a variable, but how do I take that value and send it to be used within a prompt.  I know I want to `send` it but I think I keep sending the alias and not the value as I am getting an access error.  How do I send the value and not the alias?  I'm kind of new to expect scripting so any insight is appreciated.

`expect` script as produced with golang:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c:
spawn ssh root@a.b.c.d
sleep 3
expect "# "
send "yum -y update\r"
sleep 10
expect "# "
send "yum -y upgrade\r"
sleep 10
expect "# "
send "yum -y localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm\r"
sleep 8
expect "# "
send "yum -y --disablerepo=mysql80-community --enablerepo=mysql57-community install mysql-community-server\r"
sleep 5
expect "# "
send "service mysqld start\r"
sleep 3
expect "# "
send "temppass=\$\(grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -l\)\r"
sleep 1
expect "# "
send "shortpass=\${temppass:\(-12\)}\r"
sleep 1
expect "# "
send "echo \$shortpass\r"
sleep 1
expect "# "
send "mysql_secure_installation\r"
sleep 10
expect "Enter password for user root: "
send "\$shortpass\r"
sleep 10
expect "New password: "
send "<pass>\r"
sleep 10
expect "Re-enter new password: "
send "<pass>\r"
sleep 10
expect "Change the password for root ? \(\(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) : "
send "y\r"
sleep 10
expect "New password: "
send "<pass>\r"
sleep 10
expect "Re-enter new password: "
send "<pass>\r"
sleep 10
expect "Remove anonymous users? \(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) : "
send "y\r"
sleep 10
expect "Disallow root login remotely? \(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) : "
send "n\r"
sleep 10
expect "Remove test database and access to it? \(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) : "
send "y\r"
sleep 10
expect "Reload privilege tables now? \(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) : "
send "y\r"
sleep 10
```

Actual output:

```
spawn ssh root@a.b.c.d
Last login: Mon Apr 29 13:25:07 2019 from t.x.y.z
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No packages marked for update
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# yum -y upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No packages marked for update
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# yum -y localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                              |  25 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-S1evUc/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm: mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-S1evUc/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Nothing to do
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# yum -y --disablerepo=mysql80-community --enablerepo=mysql57-community install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package matching mysql-community-server-5.7.26-1.el7.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# temppass=$(grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -l)
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# shortpass=${temppass:(-12)}
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# echo $shortpass
e3H-*HGHu__7
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# <pass>
-bash: Mysqlpass1!: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# <pass>
-bash: Mysqlpass1!: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# y
-bash: y: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# <pass>
-bash: Mysqlpass1!: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# <pass>
-bash: Mysqlpass1!: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# y
-bash: y: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# n
-bash: n: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]# y
-bash: y: command not found
[root@rias-e2e-server-a-segment-purv ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the best thing to do is to use a programming language to inject whatever you want.  I did this by exiting the sequence of commands that I wanted to run after the data I wanted was printed to the screen.  At that point the buffer has the data I'm looking for, so I can get it from there and then continue with a new sequence that injects that value where I want.